# How to bind Time field in gridview with 'HH:mm' format

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a time(7) MSSQL column name AMB, I want to display it in a GridView to the format like "16:00". right now i am using the code below:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AMB" DataFormatString="{0:t}" HeaderText="AMB" HtmlEncode="False" />
```

But it displays like 16:00:00.
How can I display a time field in gridview just with hour and minute, but no seconds?